# Чем потребляется память Linux ВМ

Tags: linux, память

Подскажите как определить кто потребил всю резидентную память ВМ?
Свободной памяти осталось очень мало и хотелось бы понимать куда она задействована, чтобы оптимизировать работу ВМ.
Исходя из анализа информации top, free, /proc/meminfo ответ на данный вопрос получить не удалось.
Кэшев и буферов мало, объем tmpfs несущественен.
Советы по аналогичным вопросам, размещенным на иных сайтах, также не поспособствовали решению вопроса.

```
uname -a
Linux vm 4.9.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.110-3+deb9u6 (2018-10-08) x86_64 GNU/Linux



top - 12:49:43 up 184 days, 13:07,  1 user,  load average: 0.83, 0.55, 0.51
Tasks: 112 total,   2 running, 110 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  2.4 us,  6.1 sy,  0.0 ni, 35.6 id, 55.6 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.3 st
KiB Mem :  2025604 total,    69620 free,  1910540 used,    45444 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  1167356 total,   631316 free,   536040 used.    15744 avail Mem 

   PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                                         
  3441 root      20   0  379.7m  72.8m   2.2m S  2.0  3.7   9:23.27                                                                                                                                      
116221 user      20   0  221.4m  15.1m   5.3m R  2.3  0.8   0:17.10 apache2                                                                                                                                         
 43921 mysql     20   0  620.6m  13.9m   0.0m S  0.3  0.7  75:38.41 mysqld                                                                                                                                          
122039 user      20   0  215.9m   8.1m   2.5m S  0.0  0.4   0:11.83 apache2                                                                                                                                         
  9200 root      20   0  419.2m   6.2m   0.0m S  0.0  0.3  12:09.54                                                                                                                                         
   708 user      20   0  215.8m   6.0m   2.3m S  0.0  0.3   0:02.13 apache2                                                                                                                                         
123857 user      20   0  214.2m   2.7m   1.8m S  0.0  0.1   0:13.64 apache2                                                                                                                                         
  3439 root      20   0    3.7m   2.7m   2.2m S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00                                                                                                                                      
  3017 root      20   0   75.1m   2.5m   2.3m S  0.0  0.1   0:00.05 sshd                                                                                                                                            
  3039 root      20   0   10.0m   1.8m   1.5m S  0.0  0.1   0:00.03 bash                                                                                                                                            
  3090 root      20   0   29.2m   1.6m   1.3m R  0.3  0.1   0:00.13 top                                                                                                                                             
 90796 zabbix    20   0   70.6m   1.3m   1.2m S  0.0  0.1   0:44.47 zabbix_agentd                                                                                                                                   
 90795 zabbix    20   0   70.6m   1.0m   1.0m S  0.0  0.1   0:43.47 zabbix_agentd                                                                                                                                   
 90794 zabbix    20   0   70.6m   1.0m   1.0m S  0.0  0.1   0:44.95 zabbix_agentd                                                                                                                                   
 90797 zabbix    20   0   70.5m   0.9m   0.8m S  0.0  0.0   0:26.30 zabbix_agentd                                                                                                                                   
 34705 root      20   0   10.5m   0.8m   0.4m S  0.3  0.0   1:25.42 containerd-shim                                                                                                                                 
 44007 root      20   0   15.1m   0.8m   0.8m S  0.0  0.0   0:06.32 cron                                                                                                                                            
128192 user      20   0  213.6m   0.7m   0.0m S  0.0  0.0   0:03.74 apache2                                                                                                                                         
   461 root      20   0  527.7m   0.5m   0.0m S  0.0  0.0 287:58.78 containerd                                                                                                                                      
     1 root      20   0  272.0m   0.5m   0.2m S  0.0  0.0   4:10.23 systemd                                                                                                                                         
 90793 zabbix    20   0   70.5m   0.4m   0.3m S  0.0  0.0   2:06.32 zabbix_agentd                                                                                                                                   
   697 user      20   0  214.1m   0.4m   0.0m S  0.0  0.0   0:02.16 apache2                                                                                                                                         
126328 user      20   0  213.6m   0.3m   0.0m S  0.0  0.0   0:06.68 apache2                                                                                                                                         
122052 user      20   0  213.7m   0.3m   0.0m S  0.0  0.0   0:15.71 apache2                                                                                                                                         
122051 user      20   0  215.3m   0.3m   0.0m S  0.0  0.0   0:13.00 apache2                                                                                                                                         
129153 user      20   0  214.1m   0.2m   0.0m S  0.0  0.0   0:03.70 apache2                                                                                                                                         
  1024 ntp       20   0   99.7m   0.1m   0.0m S  0.0  0.0  16:46.65 ntpd                                                                                                                                            
   386 root      20   0  248.5m   0.1m   0.0m S  0.0  0.0  26:07.41 rsyslogd                                                                                                                                        
   382 message+  20   0   44.2m   0.1m   0.0m S  0.0  0.0   0:30.61 dbus-daemon                                                                                                                                     
 34768 root      20   0  213.5m   0.0m   0.0m S  0.0  0.0   0:29.54 apache2                                                                                                                                         
   205 root      20   0   55.5m   0.0m   0.0m S  0.0  0.0  84:11.04 systemd-journal                                                                                                                                 
   245 root      20   0   45.6m   0.0m   0.0m S  0.0  0.0   0:22.16 systemd-udevd  


free -wh


              total        used        free      shared     buffers       cache   available
Mem:           1.9G        1.8G         68M        744K        3.6M         47M         18M
Swap:          1.1G        517M        622M


cat /proc/meminfo 


MemTotal:        2025604 kB
MemFree:           69636 kB
MemAvailable:      13852 kB
Buffers:            3064 kB
Cached:            25872 kB
SwapCached:        15432 kB
Active:            35604 kB
Inactive:          39664 kB
Active(anon):      24580 kB
Inactive(anon):    24728 kB
Active(file):      11024 kB
Inactive(file):    14936 kB
Unevictable:       75148 kB
Mlocked:           75148 kB
SwapTotal:       1167356 kB
SwapFree:         635620 kB
Dirty:                68 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:        117752 kB
Mapped:            19560 kB
Shmem:               736 kB
Slab:              92760 kB
SReclaimable:      13312 kB
SUnreclaim:        79448 kB
KernelStack:        5376 kB
PageTables:         9476 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     2180156 kB
Committed_AS:    1904772 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:           0 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:      518140 kB
DirectMap2M:     1701888 kB

smem -wtk
Area                           Used      Cache   Noncache 
firmware/hardware                 0          0          0 
kernel image                      0          0          0 
kernel dynamic memory          1.7G      22.4M       1.7G 
userspace memory             128.6M      17.1M     111.5M 
free memory                   74.9M      74.9M          0 
----------------------------------------------------------
                               1.9G     114.5M       1.8G 


ps aux --sort -rss


USER        PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root       3441  0.3  3.6 388824 74508 ?        SLl  Nov27   9:24 
mysql     43921  1.2  0.5 635532 10928 ?        Ssl  Nov25  75:40 /usr/sbin/mysqld
user     122051  0.4  0.4 221056  8704 ?        S    11:57   0:14 /usr/sbin/apache2 -D FOREGROUND
user     123857  0.4  0.3 218800  6616 ?        S    12:02   0:14 /usr/sbin/apache2 -D FOREGROUND
root       9200  0.3  0.3 429216  6368 ?        Ssl  Nov26  12:10 
user     116221  0.3  0.1 219308  3224 ?        S    11:31   0:17 /usr/sbin/apache2 -D FOREGROUND
root       3039  0.0  0.1  10268  3116 pts/0    Ss   12:48   0:00 -bash
root       4131  0.0  0.1  23368  2856 pts/0    R+   12:54   0:00 ps aux --sort -rss
root       3439  0.0  0.1   3772  2724 ?        SL   Nov27   0:00 
root       3017  0.0  0.1  76940  2708 ?        Ss   12:48   0:00 sshd: root@pts/0
zabbix    90795  0.0  0.0  72312  1540 ?        S    Nov26   0:43 /usr/sbin/zabbix_agentd: listener #2 [waiting for connection]
zabbix    90796  0.0  0.0  72312  1452 ?        S    Nov26   0:44 /usr/sbin/zabbix_agentd: listener #3 [waiting for connection]
zabbix    90797  0.0  0.0  72204  1420 ?        S    Nov26   0:26 /usr/sbin/zabbix_agentd: active checks #1 [idle 1 sec]
zabbix    90794  0.0  0.0  72312  1412 ?        S    Nov26   0:44 /usr/sbin/zabbix_agentd: listener #1 [waiting for connection]
root          1  0.0  0.0 278524  1120 ?        Ss   May28   4:10 /sbin/init
user        697  0.3  0.0 219276  1044 ?        S    12:37   0:03 /usr/sbin/apache2 -D FOREGROUND
root      44007  0.0  0.0  15504   828 ?        Ss   Nov25   0:06 /usr/sbin/cron -f
root        205  0.0  0.0  56828   784 ?        Ss   May28  84:11 /lib/systemd/systemd-journald
root        461  0.1  0.0 540340   576 ?        Ssl  May28 287:59 /usr/bin/containerd
zabbix    90793  0.0  0.0  72204   448 ?        S    Nov26   2:06 /usr/sbin/zabbix_agentd: collector [idle 1 sec]
user       3445  0.0  0.0 218956   424 ?        S    12:50   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -D FOREGROUND
user       3404  0.3  0.0 219236   408 ?        S    12:50   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -D FOREGROUND
root      34705  0.0  0.0  10740   396 ?        Sl   Nov25   1:25 containerd-shim -namespace moby -workdir /var/lib/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux/moby/b455c0425a4f6f5c769572fd2d1a00ab3c72a55ccd1f81570
user     129153  0.2  0.0 218788   384 ?        S    12:26   0:04 /usr/sbin/apache2 -D FOREGROUND
user     122039  0.3  0.0 221048   300 ?        S    11:57   0:11 /usr/sbin/apache2 -D FOREGROUND
user     122052  0.4  0.0 218800   288 ?        S    11:57   0:16 /usr/sbin/apache2 -D FOREGROUND
message+    382  0.0  0.0  45264   224 ?        Ss   May28   0:30 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation
root      10361  0.5  0.0 195016   204 ?        Sl   Nov26  18:44 
ntp        1024  0.0  0.0 102104   132 ?        Ssl  May28  16:46 /usr/sbin/ntpd -p /var/run/ntpd.pid -g -u 107:111
root        378  0.0  0.0  46868    68 ?        Ss   May28   0:48 /lib/systemd/systemd-logind
root        245  0.0  0.0  46708    48 ?        Ss   May28   0:22 /lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
root      34768  0.0  0.0 218576    44 ?        S    Nov25   0:29 /usr/sbin/apache2 -D FOREGROUND
user       3391  0.0  0.0 218684    32 ?        S    12:50   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -D FOREGROUND
root        386  0.0  0.0 254460    20 ?        Ssl  May28  26:07 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n
root        540  0.0  0.0  69952    20 ?        Ss   May28   0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
root        447  0.0  0.0 475080    16 ?        Ssl  May28  68:18 /usr/bin/dockerd -H unix://
root       9091  0.0  0.0 162992    16 ?        Ss   Nov26   0:15 
root      10362  0.1  0.0 100976    12 ?        Sl   Nov26   5:49 
root        415  0.0  0.0  20476     8 ?        Ss   May28   0:00 /sbin/dhclient -4 -v -pf /run/dhclient.eth0.pid -lf /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.eth0.leases -I -df /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient6.eth0.leases eth0
root          2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    May28   0:06 [kthreadd]
root          3  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    May28  16:15 [ksoftirqd/0]


df -h


Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                         978M     0  978M   0% /dev
tmpfs                        198M   21M  178M  11% /run
/dev/mapper/g-root           19G  6.4G   12G  37% /
tmpfs                        990M     0  990M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                        5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                        990M     0  990M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/g-home           185M  2.2M  167M   2% /home
/dev/xvda1                   236M   81M  143M  37% /boot
overlay                       19G  6.4G   12G  37% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/b877bdbc6e99b6b3c9d3aff721bd1e24d0925ad48de0b0b9f945b54abdd2fa20/merged
shm                           64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/b455c0425a4f6f5c769572fd2d1a00ab3c72a55ccd1f8157091412740247970d/mounts/shm
tmpfs                        198M     0  198M   0% /run/user/0




cat /proc/slabinfo
slabinfo - version: 2.1
# name            <active_objs> <num_objs> <objsize> <objperslab> <pagesperslab> : tunables <limit> <batchcount> <sharedfactor> : slabdata <active_slabs> <num_slabs> <sharedavail>
nf_conntrack_expect      0      0    224   18    1 : tunables  120   60    8 : slabdata      0      0      0
nf_conntrack         194    224    256   16    1 : tunables  120   60    8 : slabdata     14     14      0
au_vdir                0      0     64   64    1 : tunables  120   60    8 : slabdata      0      0      0
au_finfo               0      0    128   32    1 : tunables  120   60    8 : slabdata      0      0      0
au_icntnr              0      0    704    5    1 : tunables   54   27    8 : slabdata      0      0      0
au_dinfo               0      0    128   32    1 : tunables  120   60    8 : slabdata      0      0      0
ext4_groupinfo_1k     31     60    136   30    1 : tunables  120   60    8 : slabdata      2      2      0
ext4_groupinfo_4k    150    168    144   28    1 : tunables  120   60    8 : slabdata      6      6      0
ext4_inode_cache    1410   1764   1072    3    1 : tunables   24   12    8 : slabdata    582    588      7
ext4_allocation_context      2     32    128   32    1 : tunables  120   60    8 : slabdata      1      1      0
ext4_io_end            2     64     64   64    1 : tunables  120   60    8 : slabdata      1      1      0
ext4_extent_status    474    990     40   99    1 : tunables  120   60    8 : slabdata     10     10     84
jbd2_journal_head      9     36    112   36    1 : tunables  120   60    8 : slabdata      1      1      0
jbd2_revoke_table_s      4    240     16  240    1 : tunables  120   60    8 : slabdata      1      1      0
jbd2_revoke_record_s      0      0     32  124    1 : tunables  120   60    8 : slabdata      0      0      0
fscrypt_info           0      0     24  163    1 : tunables  120   60    8 : slabdata      0      0      0
fscrypt_ctx            8     83     48   83    1 : tunables  120   60    8 : slabdata      1      1      0
mbcache                0      0     56   71    1 : tunables  120   60    8 : slabdata      0      0      0
kcopyd_job             0      0   3312    2    2 : tunables   24   12    8 : slabdata      0      0      0
dm_uevent              0      0   2632    3    2 : tunables   24   12    8 : slabdata      0      0      0
ip6-frags              0      0    200   20    1 : tunables  120   60    8 : slabdata      0      0      0
tw_sock_TCPv6          4     17    240   17    1 : tunables  120   60    8 : slabdata      1      1      0
request_sock_TCPv6      0      0    296   13    1 : tunables   54   27    8 : slabdata      0      0      0
TCPv6                  5      6   2048    2    1 : tunables   24   12    8 : slabdata      3      3      0
cfq_queue              0      0    240   17    1 : tunables  120   60    8 : slabdata      0      0      0
bsg_cmd                0      0    312   13    1 : tunables   54   27    8 : slabdata      0      0      0
mqueue_inode_cache      2      4    896    4    1 : tunables   54   27    8 : slabdata      1      1      0
userfaultfd_ctx_cache      0      0    128   32    1 : tunables  120   60    8 : slabdata      0      0      0
dio                   12     12    640    6    1 : tunables   54   27    8 : slabdata      2      2      0
pid_namespace          1      3   2232    3    2 : tunables   24   12    8 : slabdata      1      1      0
posix_timers_cache      0      0    216   18    1 : tunables  120   60    8 : slabdata      0      0      0
ip4-frags              0      0    184   22    1 : tunables  120   60    8 : slabdata      0      0      0
flow_cache             0      0    112   36    1 : tunables  120   60    8 : slabdata      0      0      0
xfrm_dst_cache         0      0    448    9    1 : tunables   54   27    8 : slabdata      0      0      0
RAW                  512    512    896    4    1 : tunables   54   27    8 : slabdata    128    128      0
UDP                    7      8    960    4    1 : tunables   54   27    8 : slabdata      2      2      0
tw_sock_TCP           85     85    240   17    1 : tunables  120   60    8 : slabdata      5      5      0
request_sock_TCP      13     13    296   13    1 : tunables   54   27    8 : slabdata      1      1      0
TCP                   10     10   1920    2    1 : tunables   24   12    8 : slabdata      5      5      0
hugetlbfs_inode_cache      2      6    600    6    1 : tunables   54   27    8 : slabdata      1      1      0
dquot                  4     16    256   16    1 : tunables  120   60    8 : slabdata      1      1      0
request_queue         12     12   2240    3    2 : tunables   24   12    8 : slabdata      4      4      0
blkdev_requests      428    462    368   11    1 : tunables   54   27    8 : slabdata     42     42      0
blkdev_ioc           198    273    104   39    1 : tunables  120   60    8 : slabdata      7      7      0
user_namespace         0      0    424    9    1 : tunables   54   27    8 : slabdata      0      0      0
dmaengine-unmap-256      1      3   2112    3    2 : tunables   24   12    8 : slabdata      1      1      0
dmaengine-unmap-128    270    273   1088    7    2 : tunables   24   12    8 : slabdata     39     39      0
sock_inode_cache     930   1008    640    6    1 : tunables   54   27    8 : slabdata    168    168      0
file_lock_cache       28     38    208   19    1 : tunables  120   60    8 : slabdata      2      2      0
net_namespace          1      1   5568    1    2 : tunables    8    4    0 : slabdata      1      1      0
shmem_inode_cache    932   1276    688   11    2 : tunables   54   27    8 : slabdata    116    116      0
pool_workqueue        17     32    256   16    1 : tunables  120   60    8 : slabdata      2      2      0
taskstats              9     12    328   12    1 : tunables   54   27    8 : slabdata      1      1      0
proc_inode_cache     308    396    640    6    1 : tunables   54   27    8 : slabdata     65     66    172
sigqueue              25     25    160   25    1 : tunables  120   60    8 : slabdata      1      1      0
bdev_cache            10     12    832    4    1 : tunables   54   27    8 : slabdata      3      3      0
kernfs_node_cache  23094  24208    120   34    1 : tunables  120   60    8 : slabdata    712    712      0
mnt_cache            188    230    384   10    1 : tunables   54   27    8 : slabdata     23     23      0
inode_cache         8604   8911    584    7    1 : tunables   54   27    8 : slabdata   1272   1273      0
dentry             11640  17661    192   21    1 : tunables  120   60    8 : slabdata    841    841    265
iint_cache             0      0     72   56    1 : tunables  120   60    8 : slabdata      0      0      0
buffer_head          983   1755    104   39    1 : tunables  120   60    8 : slabdata     45     45      0
vm_area_struct      8589  10260    200   20    1 : tunables  120   60    8 : slabdata    513    513    231
fs_cache             242    882     64   63    1 : tunables  120   60    8 : slabdata     14     14      0
files_cache          199    297    704   11    2 : tunables   54   27    8 : slabdata     27     27      0
signal_cache         313    427   1088    7    2 : tunables   24   12    8 : slabdata     61     61      0
sighand_cache        250    273   2112    3    2 : tunables   24   12    8 : slabdata     91     91      0
task_struct          346    351   3776    1    1 : tunables   24   12    8 : slabdata    346    351      0
cred_jar             405    882    192   21    1 : tunables  120   60    8 : slabdata     42     42      0
Acpi-Operand        3168   3248     72   56    1 : tunables  120   60    8 : slabdata     58     58      0
Acpi-Parse           183    568     56   71    1 : tunables  120   60    8 : slabdata      8      8      8
Acpi-State             0      0     80   51    1 : tunables  120   60    8 : slabdata      0      0      0
Acpi-Namespace      1594   1683     40   99    1 : tunables  120   60    8 : slabdata     17     17      0
anon_vma_chain      8572  12096     64   64    1 : tunables  120   60    8 : slabdata    189    189    173
anon_vma            3963   5768     72   56    1 : tunables  120   60    8 : slabdata    103    103     12
pid                  245    576    128   32    1 : tunables  120   60    8 : slabdata     18     18      0
numa_policy          127    163     24  163    1 : tunables  120   60    8 : slabdata      1      1      0
radix_tree_node     2030   3038    576    7    1 : tunables   54   27    8 : slabdata    432    434     20
trace_event_file    1233   1242     88   46    1 : tunables  120   60    8 : slabdata     27     27      0
ftrace_event_field   3053   4482     48   83    1 : tunables  120   60    8 : slabdata     54     54      0
idr_layer_cache      303    306   2096    3    2 : tunables   24   12    8 : slabdata    102    102      0
task_group            84    105    576    7    1 : tunables   54   27    8 : slabdata     15     15      0
dma-kmalloc-4194304      0      0 4194304    1 1024 : tunables    1    1    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
dma-kmalloc-2097152      0      0 2097152    1  512 : tunables    1    1    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
dma-kmalloc-1048576      0      0 1048576    1  256 : tunables    1    1    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
dma-kmalloc-524288      0      0 524288    1  128 : tunables    1    1    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
dma-kmalloc-262144      0      0 262144    1   64 : tunables    1    1    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
dma-kmalloc-131072      0      0 131072    1   32 : tunables    8    4    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
dma-kmalloc-65536      0      0  65536    1   16 : tunables    8    4    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
dma-kmalloc-32768      0      0  32768    1    8 : tunables    8    4    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
dma-kmalloc-16384      0      0  16384    1    4 : tunables    8    4    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
dma-kmalloc-8192       0      0   8192    1    2 : tunables    8    4    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
dma-kmalloc-4096       0      0   4096    1    1 : tunables   24   12    8 : slabdata      0      0      0
dma-kmalloc-2048       0      0   2048    2    1 : tunables   24   12    8 : slabdata      0      0      0
dma-kmalloc-1024       0      0   1024    4    1 : tunables   54   27    8 : slabdata      0      0      0
dma-kmalloc-512        0      0    512    8    1 : tunables   54   27    8 : slabdata      0      0      0
dma-kmalloc-256        0      0    256   16    1 : tunables  120   60    8 : slabdata      0      0      0
dma-kmalloc-128        0      0    128   32    1 : tunables  120   60    8 : slabdata      0      0      0
dma-kmalloc-64         0      0     64   64    1 : tunables  120   60    8 : slabdata      0      0      0
dma-kmalloc-32         0      0     32  124    1 : tunables  120   60    8 : slabdata      0      0      0
dma-kmalloc-192        0      0    192   21    1 : tunables  120   60    8 : slabdata      0      0      0
dma-kmalloc-96         0      0    128   32    1 : tunables  120   60    8 : slabdata      0      0      0
kmalloc-4194304        0      0 4194304    1 1024 : tunables    1    1    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
kmalloc-2097152        0      0 2097152    1  512 : tunables    1    1    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
kmalloc-1048576        0      0 1048576    1  256 : tunables    1    1    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
kmalloc-524288         0      0 524288    1  128 : tunables    1    1    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
kmalloc-262144         1      1 262144    1   64 : tunables    1    1    0 : slabdata      1      1      0
kmalloc-131072         3      3 131072    1   32 : tunables    8    4    0 : slabdata      3      3      0
kmalloc-65536          1      1  65536    1   16 : tunables    8    4    0 : slabdata      1      1      0
kmalloc-32768          3      3  32768    1    8 : tunables    8    4    0 : slabdata      3      3      0
kmalloc-16384         20     20  16384    1    4 : tunables    8    4    0 : slabdata     20     20      0
kmalloc-8192          42     42   8192    1    2 : tunables    8    4    0 : slabdata     42     42      0
kmalloc-4096        5433   5433   4096    1    1 : tunables   24   12    8 : slabdata   5433   5433      0
kmalloc-2048        4400   4408   2048    2    1 : tunables   24   12    8 : slabdata   2204   2204      0
kmalloc-1024        5406   7180   1024    4    1 : tunables   54   27    8 : slabdata   1795   1795      0
kmalloc-512        22322  22560    512    8    1 : tunables   54   27    8 : slabdata   2820   2820      0
kmalloc-256         6146  15440    256   16    1 : tunables  120   60    8 : slabdata    965    965    240
kmalloc-192         4740   5166    192   21    1 : tunables  120   60    8 : slabdata    246    246      0
kmalloc-96          6590  19712    128   32    1 : tunables  120   60    8 : slabdata    616    616      0
kmalloc-64         17020  29696     64   64    1 : tunables  120   60    8 : slabdata    464    464     96
kmalloc-32         31021  35216     32  124    1 : tunables  120   60    8 : slabdata    284    284      0
kmalloc-node       12996  21632    128   32    1 : tunables  120   60    8 : slabdata    676    676      0
kmem_cache         11437  15876    192   21    1 : tunables  120   60    8 : slabdata    756    756      0
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101648/discussion-on-question-by-good23----linux-).

Answer (score 1):

а что за пид 3441 у вас который съел 3,6% памяти и при этом не отображается имя процесса?

Для подсчёта куда ушла память я бы рекомендовал что-то вроде такого скрипта:

```
cat ./mem.pl  
#!/usr/bin/perl


use feature(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($mem,undef);

&mem;


#список процессов по занимаемой памяти:   
sub mem{

my %mem=();

unless ( open(MEMINFO,"cat /proc/meminfo|") ){
        print "ErrorOpenPipe"; # if ( defined $options{d} );
}

while (<MEMINFO>){
        my @mem_param = split;
        $mem_param[0] =~ s/://g;
        $mem{$mem_param[0]}=$mem_param[1];
}

my $LOW=`echo "\$(getconf PAGESIZE)/1024"|bc;`*`grep low /proc/zoneinfo |awk 'BEGIN {FS = \" \"} ; {sum+=\$2} END {print sum}'`;
my $free_mem_proc=int((($mem{MemFree}+$mem{Buffers}+$mem{Cached}+$mem{SReclaimable}-$mem{Shmem}-$LOW)*100)/$mem{MemTotal});

say "MemTotal:$mem{MemTotal} (kB)
Free memory:$free_mem_proc%";

say "SLAB Reclaimable: $mem{SReclaimable} (kB)" if (defined $mem{SReclaimable});
say "SLAB SUnreclaim: $mem{SUnreclaim} (kB)" if (defined $mem{SUnreclaim});

say "x" x 50;

        $mem = `ps -eo rss,pid,user,command --sort -size | awk '{ hr=\$1/1024 ; printf("%13.2f Mb ",hr) } { for ( x=4 ; x<=NF ; x++ ) { printf("%s ",\$x) } {print \$2} print "" }' | egrep -v 0.00 |sort -n | awk '{print  \$1\$2"  "\$NF"  "\$3 }'|tail`;

        print "Top process by memory use:\n MEM\t  PID\t\t Command \n$mem\n";

}
```

Пример вывода:

```
./mem.pl
MemTotal:6102748 (kB)
Free memory:28%
SLAB Reclaimable: 83772 (kB)
SLAB SUnreclaim: 89020 (kB)
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Top process by memory use:
 MEM      PID            Command 
172.10Mb  1713  /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg
185.82Mb  22798  /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser
226.70Mb  6578  /usr/lib/vk/vk
229.81Mb  22433  /mnt/stor/home/zersh/Telegram/Telegram
230.68Mb  5033  /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser
233.48Mb  4685  /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser
233.82Mb  4194  /usr/share/skypeforlinux/skypeforlinux
299.44Mb  15091  /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser
378.27Mb  4237  /usr/lib/thunderbird/thunderbird
436.29Mb  4242  /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser
```

Comment: @good23 Можно запустить `htop` и в варианте просмотра деревом найти родителей и т.п.

Answer (score 0):

Ну очевидно, же что всю память отьел веб сервер apache2 в связке с демоном MySQL, более того - более-менее понятно, что сервер apache2 держит слишком много сессий (на это указывает размер своппинга, куда выгружены старые сессии)

Я бы подрегулировал время жизни сессий на веб сервере - это самый быстрый способ сократить потребление памяти.

Comment: Вы этот вывод сделали исходя из количества виртуальной памяти, используемой указанными процессами?